# mysql trigger display an error

Tags: mysql, triggers

i want to convert a field when a insertion takes place in one of my table.

check & ged's => check and geds.

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE
    TRIGGER `perma_limk_insertion` AFTER INSERT
    ON `tbl_magazine`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    DECLARE magazine_name VARCHAR(100); 
    @magazine_name := REPLACE(FieldName,'&','and');
    @magazine_name := REPLACE(FieldName,"'",'');
    UPDATE tbl_magazine SET perma_link = magazine_name WHERE MAGAZINE_ID = NEW.MAGAZINE_ID;
   END$$
   DELIMITER ;
```

this is my trigger. but i got an error that

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@magazine_name := REPLACE(FieldName,'&','and'); @magazine_name := REPLA' at line 7
```

if any one know about this. please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [13.7.4. SET Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-statement.html).

```
...
SET @magazine_name := REPLACE(FieldName,'&','and');
SET @magazine_name := REPLACE(FieldName,"'",'');
...
```

When or where is define the variable: FieldName?

You should also check the logic. For example `@magazine_name` is a [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) and `magazine_name VARCHAR(100)` one [13.6.4.1. Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html), are different variables.

In this case, it will assign `NULL` to the column `perma_link`, because it is the value of `magazine_name` (never assigned), the variable is being assigned `@magazine_name`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change variable `FieldName` to name of column you want to run function REPLACE on (in this case column name `perma_link`).

Your code will be:

```
...
@magazine_name := REPLACE(perma_link,'&','and');
@magazine_name := REPLACE(perma_link,"'",'');
UPDATE tbl_magazine SET perma_link = magazine_name WHERE MAGAZINE_ID = NEW.MAGAZINE_ID;
...
```